# TuesPechkin: IIS-hosted application

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget-package, converters, tuespechkin

I'm having trouble trying to setup the PDF to HTML converter from the `TuesPechkin` Nuget package.  I have it set up like mentioned [here](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin):

This is my code in my `aspx.cs` page:

```
private static IConverter converter = 
    new ThreadSafeConverter(
        new RemotingToolset<PdfToolset>(
            new Win64EmbeddedDeployment(
                new TempFolderDeployment())));
```

Everything goes fine except the `Win64EmbeddedDeployment` part says:

> The type or namespace name 'Win64EmbeddedDeployment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Anyone know how to do resolve this and if I'm going on the right track here?

Comment: I suppose you've installed the package TuesPechkin.Wkhtmltox.Win64 as well. It contains the class Win64EmbeddedDeployment. Am I right? Is your application pool running in 64-bit mode? If it is running in 32-bit mode, .NET framework is not able to load the 64-bit specific library. If you want to run in 32-bit mode, install the package TuesPechkin.Wkhtmltox.Win32 and use the class Win32EmbeddedDeployment.

Comment: That answers that, thanks.  I just blindly assumed that those would fall under the main tuespechkin package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need install one more nuget for `Win64EmbeddedDeployment` or `Win32EmbeddedDeployment`.

Comment: And this nuget package is: `TuesPechkin.Wkhtmltox.Win64` or `TuesPechkin.Wkhtmltox.Win32` for `Win32EmbeddedDeployment` class.

Answer (score 0):

Need to install nuget: `TuesPechkin.Wkhtmltox.Win64`.